# Selenium and datepicker fighting?

Tags: jquery, python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I am trying to create a selenium test in python, and I am getting inconsistent results.

The fragment of my test is:

```
    el = self.waitButton('edit') # wait for load of show page to complete.
    # check some fields
    els = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='info']")
    assert els[0].text == '2'
    assert els[1].text == "George's"
    assert els[2].text == 'Organisation'
    assert els[5].text == '25/Mar/15'
    el.click() # request for edit screen
    el = self.waitButton('save') # returns save button when edit screen loaded.
    x = browser.find_element_by_name('Status')
    # x.click()  # uncomment this line and the click two lines down is ignored
    el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='save']") # re-find save button
    el.click()  # this field is selected, but the click action does not happen
    el = self.waitButton('edit')  # wait for edit button to appear
    els = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='info']")
    assert els[5].text == '25/Mar/15'
```

First thing to note is that very similar code works 100% on three other tests, on pages that don't contain a datepicker field.If I change the class of the datapicker field to datepickerXX this screen works as expected.

However, with datepicker active, if I click into any data field (not necessarily the datepicker field), then I cannot later click on the "save" button????

So my question is how can I *reliably* test an edit screen that contains a field with datepicker in use, if I can't save it? Does anyone know (or like to guess) what might be happening, and why it is failing?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

There was two things wrong with my code.

1) Elsewhere I had a timing eror - I was waiting for something that was true on the previous screen and thus the wait sometimes did and sometimes did not wait for the new screen.

2) When you click on select field or tab into it, the browser (FF) will display a selection list. Both Selenium and the browser know this - they just disagree on when the selection list is hidden again. The browser will hide it if another field is clicked. Selenium requires that a selection is clicked, and if it isn't gets in a muddle.

Once I had sorted both this problems, the tests all worked as required.